# How is supersonic rocket exhaust able to match sea-level pressures?

Tags: rockets, propulsion

I understand that the diverging portion of a rocket nozzle speeds up the flow and also expands it, in order to best match ambient pressure outside. However, doesn't higher speed flow lower the pressure, and even if it is expanding its still moving much faster than the low pressure ambient it's entering. Doesn't that create a large pressure differential?

Comment: Try to google "Sutton Biblarz rocket propulsion". There is chapter "Rocket exhaust plumes". I'm not providing a link because I'm not sure about copyright.

Comment: The gases in the combustion chamber are at high pressure. They expand in the nozzle to somewhere around ambient. If you notice, nozzles for space are longer than nozzles for launch and the larger expansion ratio for vacuum is the reason.